How to banish "Your microphone is muted" bubble
When I join a Teams using Chrome, I have the mic muted.  There is a persistent popup bubble telling me "Your microphone is muted" which obstructs the presentation slides.  There is no icon with which to banish the bubble.  I can make it go away momentarily by enabling and disabling the mic, but it comes back right away.
I'm assuming that this is not intended behaviour for the Teams meeting web app.  How does one banish the message bubble?
